# What part type is denoted by SKx?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication

I’m fairly well versed in component labels like C1, R12, U72, etc but while taking apart a small external hard drive I found a component which looks to be made of ceramic labelled SK1.

Now, crystals should be marked as Yx (where x is a number) and both ends seem to terminate at a chip, but is this a standard part label? Other oscillators on the board are labelled as you’d expect.

[image]

Comment: Some varistor perhaps? Can you zoom out a bit and follow the trace to the left?

Comment: Please see our [Component Identification Question Guidelines](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6710/11683). As it stands, your question currently does not meet several of the requirements. Please take another picture that's in focus!

Comment: Thanks folks! I’ve already thrown out the PCB so not much luck. I hadn’t expected to learn exactly what part *this* is in question, but what part type is denoted by “SK”. Sorry if the photo started a goose chase. For what it’s worth, both leads fed back to the IC through R4 and R53.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the asker has thrown away the component in question and thus it is not available for further investigation.

Comment: It's not an identification question. It's a perfectly fine question about PCB layout and best-practices naming.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> while taking apart a small external hard drive I found a component which looks to be made of ceramic labelled SK1

It's a *shock sensor* used by the hard drive controller (hence the choice of "SK" for the designator makes sense  - **S**hoc**K**).

For example, here is the product page for this type of ceramic-package shock / vibration sensor, made by Murata, containing cantilever-mounted piezo elements:

https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/sensor/shock/consumer

Quoting from that web page:

> > Murata shock sensors find use in many computer hard disk drives. They detect impacts - for example, when the storage falls to the floor - in a fraction of a second and prevent read and write errors.

Comment: If it is necessary to mount it at a 45 degree angle to allow X and Y shock detection, would there not be a diagonal direction in which it cannot detect shock?

Comment: Hmm. Given that some have a “primary inclined angle” of 25 degrees that may help for Z? There is usually an accelerometer somewhere as well.

Comment: @AndreyAkhmetov - As *RandomInsano* mentioned in his comment following yours, some of these sensors have the internal piezoelectric element oriented at an angle to the X-Y plane, so they are sensitive in the Z-axis too. Also some (typically more expensive) hard drives can have multiple shock sensors in different orientations, for improved sensitivity. So in my experience, no, there isn't a direction in which they can't detect shock. That part of my answer was just trying to explain how *one* sensor could be sensitive in multiple planes, by having it mounted at an angle as shown in the photo..

Comment: @RandomInsano - Yes, my information is that the chosen sensors have Z-axis senstivity for the reason you mention, with the piezoelectric element angled internally to the X-Y planes.